# Disable user from accessing page VIA address bar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

Afternoon,

I am currently fixing a few things on my application and have come across a problem that is quite serious and never thought of before.

In my application a user has to log in and when their details have been entered it goes to the database and checks if they are there, if they are not an error message appears, if they are they will be logged in.

If the user goes to the address bar and changes the login page:

```
"/Account/nLogin.aspx"
```

To the page after the login button:

```
"PolicySearch.aspx"
```

The user will be directed to that page. Is there a way i can disable the user moving from page to page using the address bar?

Comment: are you using webforms?

Comment: @basher Nope, i am using asp.net web page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="myApp" loginUrl="/Account/nLogin.aspx" timeout="30" path="/" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This will enable forms authentication within your app, forces users to the login page via `loginUrl` and denies entry to anonymous users via `deny users="?"`. [Here's the docs for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx). Then add the following code to nLogin.aspx.vb:

```
/* after make sure user credentials are valid. */
Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false)
```

This will authorize them and redirect them to whichever page they originally requested. If they only navigated to the login page then you can use `response.redirect` to send them somewhere else. You can checkout the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx)  for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i am going to try this out now.

Comment: I have added the piece of code in but for some reason the Login Page wont even load up. I am getting "Username and Password was incorrect" popup before the page loades.

Comment: @BenClarke That isn't part of ASP.NET, that's your own code saying username & password incorrect. Try searching your code for that phrase to see where it's coming from. You can use `ctrl+shift+f` to search in all files in your project/solution.